# Unable to connect to AmazonMQ using MassTransit Via SSL

Tags: masstransit, amazon-mq

I am trying to connect to AmazonMQ using latest version of MassTransit (MassTransit.ActiveMQ 5.5.5-develop.2104) using ssl

The scheme intended to connect to AmazonMQ is SSL and I'm using the following code as mentioned in the MassTransit website.

```
 var host = cfg.Host($"{brokerId}.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", 61617, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(username);
                    h.Password(password);

                    h.UseSsl();
                });
```

Expected Results: 
Connection successful to AmazonMQ

Actual Results:
Connection cannot be established. Erroring with the exception

```
MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport.Transport.ActiveMqReceiveTransport Error: 0 : 
ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException
ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException
```

Also, I see that the underlying scheme is `activemq` instead of `SSL` inspite of using `UseSsl()`